# Linking matrices to linear equations

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations

I'd love advice on connecting two understandings of matrices as linear transformations.
If we have a system like
2x - y = 1 and
x + y = 5 ,
then we can understand it as

[image]

a scalar x times the vector (2, 1) plus a scalar y times the vector (-1, 1) results in the vector (1, 5). You can see that visually. You're trying to find how many copies of (2, 1)T plus how many copies of (-1, 1) will help you to reach (1, 5). But how do I match that with the matrix as linear transformation interpretation, that sending (1, 0) --> (2, -1) and (0, 1) --> (1, 1) results in sending (x, y) to (1, 5)? Obviously, it works out, but they feel like two very different things. In one case, x and y are scalar multipliers of the two component vectors, and in the other case (x, y) is a vector itself that gets transformed to (1, 5). How can I visually connect these two?

Comment: $\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\ 
c & d
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x \\ 
y
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
ax+by\\ 
cx+dy
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
ax\\ 
cx
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
by\\ 
dy
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
a\\ 
c
\end{pmatrix}x+\begin{pmatrix}
b\\ 
d
\end{pmatrix}y$

Comment: Or more simply, $T\begin{pmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{pmatrix}=xT\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}+yT\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
1
\end{pmatrix}$ since multiplication by a matrix T is linear. The geometric relationship would not be true if T were not linear.

Answer (score 1):

The trouble I was having was showing visually. I found a start elsewhere and connected the dots, so I'm sharing this in case it's useful. I think my sticky point was that I kept thinking of the coefficients as the multiplicative factors instead of the variables as the scalars. For example, say that we have the matrix that represents the equations 5x+1y=21 and 2x+3y = 26. Another way we can think of this is

- Take x copies of a length of 5
- Take y copies of a length of 1
- Together, those sum to 21
- Take x copies of a length of 2
- Take y copies of a length of 3
- Those sum to 26.
  This matches up with writing the equation as
  x * (5, 2) + y * (1, 3) = (21, 26) and you can draw this on graph paper.
  Then, in terms of linear transformations, you can think of that coefficient matrix as sending (1, 0) to (5, 2) and (0, 1) to (1, 3). So then the linear system, written with matrix multiplication times the vector (x, y) can be interpreted as looking for some original vector (x, y) that gets transformed to (21, 26) when (1, 0)--> (5, 2) and (0, 1) --> (1, 3). But why, right? Because in the first case, there was no vector (x, y). Instead, x and y were seen as scalars acting on vectors that represented the coefficient of the respective terms. But, we can write the vector (x, y) in terms of the basis vectors  (1, 0) and (0, 1). In other words, (x, y) = x * (1, 0) + y * (0, 1). And you can draw this on graph paper, as some number of (1, 0)s and some number of (0, 1s). But we already know where those basis vectors go to, so substitute those in. As a result, the transformed vector would be x * (5, 2) + y * (1, 3). But we already did that right? We took x copies of (5, 2) and y copies of (1, 3) when we were just thinking about linear equations, trying to guess how many copies of (5, 2) and (1, 3) would get us to (21, 26). As an earlier poster said, the fact that this is a linear transformation, that you can either transform and then add or else add and then transform, makes this possible.

Answer (score 0):

We can think of the equation $A\mathbf x = \mathbf b$ as a system of linear equations or we can think about it as a linear transformation.  The algebra of matrix multiplication should be clear enough as to why our equation is a system of linear equations, so I am not going to talk about that much.

As a linear transformation, you are correct $\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$ maps the vector $(1,0)$ to $(a,b)$ and $(0,1)$ to $(c,d).$  I hope you don't mind me using row vectors to represent the vectors in this transformation.

If our matrix is non-singular (the row / column vectors are linearly independent, the determinant is zero, and there exists an inverse matrix) then it is a 1-1 and onto mapping of the plane to its self.  That means that under this transformation, there is a unique vector $\mathbf x$ such that when the matrix $A$ transforms this vector, it maps it to $\mathbf b.$

I hope this helps.